# How to create an exclude file entry for xcopy that matches the extension of a file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, dos, xcopy

Consider the following batch statements:

```
for / %f in (C:\temp\cool\*) do if not "%~nf" == "update" 
    xcopy /r /Y /S /D:01-01-2001 /EXCLUDE:excl.txt %f c:\temp\%~nf\
```

It uses an file with a list of excludes. This `excl.txt` looks like:

> .config 
>   .log

It is supposed to skip all files log and config files. Unfortunately it is also skipping this file:

> cfw.loginpopup.js

How can I fix this problem? I only like to exclude files that *end in* a `.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm thinking too simple, but you can try this for the exclusion list:

```
*.config 
*.log
```